# FreeTDS SQL Server Invalid data type

Tags: django, linux, pyodbc

I am using Ubuntu. I want to access Microsoft sql database using pyodbc in django. I installed all requirements. To do that, I wrote this

```
cursor.execute('SELECT Id FROM %s' %table_name)
```

I am getting error which is

```
[HY004] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

But, when I try this

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable')
```

It works fine. Why do I see that error, Is there a way to solve that issue ?

Comment: When I also try this cursor.execute('SELECT Id FROM ?' ,table_name) It does not work as well. Can you provide the equivalence of that command,please ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't support variables for table names.  Try building the whole statement as a string and then executing it.

Comment: How can I do that ? Do you have an example to do that ?

Comment: You mean like that, I tried that one but no succsess........sql="SELECT Id FROM ?" cursor.execute(sql,table_name)

Comment: @JohnSmith - The '?' denotes a parameter placeholder. As mentioned above, SQL Server doesn't support parameters for [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx).